# Sort by Frequency with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to sort by Frequency the following dataset:

```
Date
03/01/2020     11
03/02/2020    105
03/03/2020     68
03/04/2020     13
03/05/2020     33
03/06/2020     23
03/07/2020     14
03/08/2020     37
03/09/2020     23
03/10/2020     36
03/11/2020     28
03/12/2020     16
03/13/2020     14
03/14/2020     10
03/15/2020     19
03/16/2020     55
03/17/2020     32
03/18/2020     24
03/19/2020     18
03/20/2020     18
03/21/2020      6
03/22/2020     11
03/23/2020     15
03/24/2020     25
03/25/2020     10
03/26/2020      6
03/27/2020     23
03/28/2020     12
03/29/2020      7
03/30/2020      8
03/31/2020     12
```

created by `file.groupby(['Date']).count()['Users']`.
How can I add a name to the Frequency (currently having no name) column and sort by Frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do `sort_values` + `to_frame` to fix your code

```
file.groupby(['Date']).count()['Users'].sort_values().to_frame('your name')
```

However, I recommend `value_counts`

```
file.Date.value_counts().to_frame('your name')
```